# Check for mui selected table row in cypress after animation

Tags: material-ui, cypress

I'm building an application which has a list represented as mui table.
There is always one entry selected in this list.
After I create an new list entry an useEffect hook will ensure that the new entry will be selected.

Now I'm writting an cypress test, which should only continue his work after the selected list entry was updated (after the list entry creation).

For this I wrote following code.
Initially the list value is "Cooler Kunde". But after the list entry creation it is "Neue Position".

```js
    cy.get('.Mui-selected.MuiTableRow-root') // I found a <tr> tag with this two classes to identify my html tag
        .children()
        .find('p')
        .should('have.text', 'Cooler Kunde'); // this works
    // doing some stuff which causes the new selected line
    cy.get('.Mui-selected.MuiTableRow-root')
        .children()
        .find('p')
        .should('have.text', 'Neue Position'); // this fails
```

But I receive the following error:

```bash
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<p.MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-body2.css-1xsg5cg-MuiTypography-root>' to have text 'Neue Position', but the text was 'Cooler Kunde'
```

But I can fix this issue by a wait. But I don't like to use a wait, which always delays my tests:

```js
    cy.get('.Mui-selected.MuiTableRow-root')
        .children()
        .find('p')
        .should('have.text', 'Cooler Kunde');
    cy.wait(1000);
    cy.get('.Mui-selected.MuiTableRow-root')
        .children()
        .find('p')
        .should('have.text', 'Neue Position');
```

Do you have an idea how I can fix this issue without using the cy.wait(1000)?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce it to `wait(0)` which will not delay the test but will allow app actions to complete.

It makes Cypress give up the thread and allows the app code to run.

Comment: The problem is, that 0 ms aren't enough for the animation, which needs some ms

Comment: But your error message says **"Timed out retrying after 4000ms"** - that's longer than the 1000ms you were waiting. It's not about waiting longer or shorter time, it's because this **"// doing some stuff which causes the new selected line"** is blocked from running.